# Can anybody unfreeze our main chat room?

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

A few days ago i found myself in a frozen [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3819).
AFAIK only the owner of a room can unfreeze a frozen room but maybe mods can do something or do we need to create a new room?

As community we should know that a frozen main chat room isn't a good promotion for our activity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As community we should know that a frozen main chat room isn't a good promotion for our activity!

To which I rebut: **As a community, we should know that an *inactive* main chat room is a worse promotion for our activity.**

The chat room was automatically frozen for inactivity: Nobody had used it, *at all*, for two weeks. And it took nine more days of *being* frozen before anyone (i.e. OP) thought to ask for an unfreeze. That's a significant length of apathy, which says quite a lot about our community.

<del>Any moderator could unfreeze it</del> I just unfroze it, but this is just going to happen again unless people actually use it. Since the [*last* time it froze automatically for activity](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28979679#28979679), it was averaging activity one in every three days, and *that* was often just one or two lines rather than anything even approaching a conversation.

Stack Exchange Chat doesn't know anything about having a "main" chat room: It just sees active rooms and inactive rooms. And even if the "main" room is inactive, it won't freeze anything unless there's already another *active* room available.

We obviously have members of our community willing to chat and keep rooms alive, since the "[Islamic Evangelism](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41959/2016/7/2)" room has been thriving since July; users are actively engaged in there, and actively concerned about keeping it from freezing. These same users, for whatever reason, just don't care about the "main" chat room, at which point even calling it the "main" chat room at all is a stretch.

So far as new users are concerned, which would you think is more welcoming: An active room with engaged users discussing topics of interest to them? Or a general chat room with pages of bot-generated meta re-posts and "*This room has been frozen for inactivity*//*A moderator has unfrozen this room*" notices?

Comment: I'm hoping that this or any other room may be an active room at least for a couple of hours each day, so my Post or Question is a call for more activity in first place!